# Are certificates supported in IBM API Connect Test and Monitor?

Tags: apiconnect, apiconnect-test-monitor

I plan to use IBM API Connect Test and Monitor for one of my customers but I can't find a way to use certificates in my tests. Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks a lot,

Dirk

Answer (score 0):

The cloud version doesn't support adding certificates but the desktop client will soon: https://github.com/ibm-apiconnect/test-and-monitor